# JsonUtils.safeEval getting error when trying to evaluate "\t" "tab" character

Tags: java, javascript, json, gwt

when I try to eval a JSON

```
{"DS_JUSTIFICATIVA":"Oxigen 30mg Cp.   Item não padronizado : testes"}
```

I getting an error, I would like to know if this error is a safeEval error or I should no permit to such thing on my JSON objects?
[image: Sample of error in jsoneditoronline.org]
Obs: probably copying and Paste will note simulates the error because the HTML render as spaces, but you can edit on notepad put a tab on it and copy past from there.